# passing environment to command in bash for loop one liner

Tags: bash

bash for i in {1..1}; do POOL_SIZE=10 bundle exec sidekiq -e production -c 50 -C ./config/sidekiq.yml & done

# => bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

what have I missed?

Comment: is `POOL_SIZE=10 bundle exec sidekiq -e production -c 50 -C ./config/sidekiq.yml` a single command?

Comment: Please format your code and error, either indent it four spaces or surround it with tildes.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a script and indeed **want to pass a list of commands as a *string* directly to the `bash` executable, use the `-c` option**, and **quote the entire string**:

```
bash -c 'for i in {1..1}; do POOL_SIZE=10 bundle exec sidekiq -e production -c 50 -C ./config/sidekiq.yml & done'
```